# Serverside Dashboard buildup (Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-server, dashboard, azure-iot-hub

I´m sending some sensordata to my azure IoT-Hub and now I want to display them on different Dashboards.
To get started I used the template from a Microsoft Tutorial and it works fine: 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/web-apps-node-iot-hub-data-visualization.git

The only problem is, that the Dashboard only show the new data that comes in for the client.
After every reload of the page (from the client side) the Dashboards are completely blank at first and then build up the data that comes up next.
(I think the client loads the script and builds the Dashboard up itself?)
I load the index.html file and in the html-file are linked some js-files.

My question is now if it´s possible to build up the Dashboards the whole time on the serverside in Node.js?
So if a client connects to my site, it automatically shows all saved data from my Dashboards (even from the past)

TLTR:
Can you generate data on Dashboards on the serverside and then just "mirror" the Dashboard to the Client?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for a solution with Dashboard that can show previous day data as well.If so you need to push data from IoT hub to some other storage like CosmosDB etc and built your custom dashboard on it.
I had a similar requirement like that and used Azure Time Series Insights for that purpose.The API would return data to UI which has Dashboard build on Angular. Have documented the same here :
http://learniotwithzain.com/2019/03/near-real-time-iot-data-exploration-using-azure-time-series-insights/

Azure Time Series Insights product has some ClientSide SDK as well. Please do check the cost associated and see if this suits your requirement.